# Enroll face using Zkteco

Tags: c#, bioinformatics, zkteco, zkemkeeper

I cannot enroll face via C# application. I can enroll directly in the device and I can access the enrolled face using the function **GetUserFaceStr**. I could do fingerprint enrollment from c# application. But device not responding to face enrollment. I'm using dll from standalone+sdk-6.3.1.37-doc-2.1.0-demo-1.1.15.In the demo application, I cannot find any code for enrolling face. In the SDK changelog.txt file, its mentioned
**2017-07-13:
1.StartEnrollEx support face online registration.**

But the function **StartEnrollEx** takes FingerID as a parameter. Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try using StartEnrollEx with `FingerIndex = 111` to enroll face.
I sent the same question to ZKteco Technical dept and received that response. I tried it was successful.